# Does nesting an itms-services URI change behavior of the protocol?

Tags: ios

I see the following snippet posted all over the internet:

```
 <a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http:/oursite.com/myApp.plist" id="text">
```

Kind of hard to believe that is a standard practice.  Is there any difference between `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=` and `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=`?

Comment: Personally not sure, but there do appear to be [some](http://gknops.github.io/adHocGenerate/) [examples](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air) of that string not being duplicated.

Comment: I've always seen it without the duplication but I've recently been told that a URL has to have that format with the duplication and I wonder why.  I'm assuming someone did a google search and found their way on to some poor example in a blog post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo, but it doesn't stop the installs working.

Probably because it forms a url like this:

```
itms-services://
 ?
  action=download-manifest
 &
  url=itms-services://?action=download-manifest
 &
  url=http:/oursite.com/myApp.plist
```

and it's probably taking the last url.

I just ran both through the [Charles Web Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and the responses (and requests) are identical. (Ignore the 401's - that is the server requesting authentication).

[image]

As you can see they both result in the same request.

But, of course this could change in the future Apple updates.

**So stick to the single itms-services version.**

Comment: Good point breaking it down into parameters.  It wouldn't actually be nested unless the `&` was url encoded.

Comment: For fun I tried it with the & encoded as $amp; and it still worked identically in the proxy trace!